# how to separate the jar file log based on the reference packages

Tags: java, log4j2

I have two packages com.temp1 and com.temp2 both are using spring,hibernate and some other jar files. i want to get separate log file for both packages. what can i change in my code.

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration status="debug">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="log_A" fileName="${path}/A_temp.log"
        filePattern="${path}/A_temp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
             <pattern><![CDATA[%d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss} "%-17c" "%m"%n]]>
             </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </RollingFile>  
    <RollingFile name="log_B" fileName="${path}/B_temp.log"
        filePattern="${path}/B_temp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
             <pattern><![CDATA["${hostName}" "${userName}" %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} "%-17c" "%m"%n]]>
             </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.temp1" level="debug">
         <appender-ref ref="log_A" level="debug"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.temp2" level="debug">
         <appender-ref ref="log_B" level="debug"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

log initialized java class

```
  private void initilizeLoggs() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

  String loggerName = null;
  loggerName = allProps.getProperty("logger.file.name");
  if(loggerName != null) {
      LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
      String pathLocation = ConectingClass.getFolderPath();
      File file = new File(pathLocation + File.separator + loggerName);
      context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
      if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
          logger.debug("Logger initialized");
      }
  }
```

Comment: what does it print out now ?

Comment: now getting log in both file. if access com.temp1 the jar file log is in both file.

Comment: show how you initialize loggers in the java class

Comment: added the initialized class

Comment: why don't you use  Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyApp.class) ? i guess, the problem in your initializer.

Comment: i can't get your answer clearly, please explain

Comment: see here how to init logger https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: I think you don't understand my problem. i have two ear file deployed in same domain.both are different project. i have single log4j2.xml property file in server domain. i separated the project log in different file it is working fine but both project are having some common jar's. if error is occur in that jar file means log is logged in both log file. so how to split that in application based?